# How can I return the name of a column rather than data it contains?

Tags: r

I am trying to get the name of an object to be printed rather than the values it represents.

Is this possible? For example how can I change the following as.character() command to return the text 'foo' and 'bar' rather than the values they represent.

```
custom_plot<-function(X, Y){
plot(X, Y, main =paste("Custom Plot ", as.character(Y), "vs.", as.character(X)))
} 

foo<-c(1,2,3)
bar<-c(2,4,5)

custom_plot(foo, bar) 
#Should make a plot with title of "Custom Plot foo vs. bar"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `substitute`

```
custom_plot<-function(X, Y){
  plot(X, Y, main =paste("Custom Plot ", substitute(Y), "vs.", substitute(X)))
}
```